# jQuery, .wrap and click in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem in IE7 using jQuery's `.wrap` function. I have a list of elements. On click I do something like this:

```
function wlt(father) {
  hlms = $(father).find('.moreSpan a').attr('href');
  tlms = $(father).find('.moreSpan a').attr('title');

  // Add/remove link on h2
  $(father).find('h2 > .bold').wrap('<a></a>');
  $('.stripClose h2 > a > .bold').unwrap();
  $(father).find('h2 > .bold').wrap('<a href="' + hlms + '" title="' + tlms + '"class="searchtitle_i"></a>');

  // Add/remove link on Showcase H2
  $(father).find('h2 > .linkAllTitle ').wrap('<a></a>');
  $('.stripClose h2 > a > .linkAllTitle').unwrap();
  $(father).find('h2 > .linkAllTitle ').wrap('<a href="' + hlms + '" title="' + tlms + '"class="searchtitle_i"></a>');
}
```

Basically in each web browser this code works: it displays the content of a div and adds a link to the `li` element clicked.

In IE7 when I click on the `li` element the page displays the content of the div and then goes to the link added by jQuery. Do you have an idea of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your click event is continuing to propagate or maybe a mouse button up event is triggering the link. Is it possible to call the wlt function like so?

```
$(father).click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation(); 
     function wlt(father);
     }
```

Comment: The jQuery API has no documented limitations of the event.stopPropagation() function. I was also unable to locate any information on this limitation elsewhere.